# How to create table output with mathematical expressions?

Tags: r, shiny, mathjax

I cannot figure out how to create output tables which contain LaTeX like math expressions.

How can I display the greek letter rho in my example?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$table <- renderTable({
    ts_summary <- data.frame(rho_1 = 1,
                             rho_2 = 2,
                             rho_3 = 3,
                             rho_4 = 4,
                             rho_5 = 5)
    ts_summary 

  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: did you check: ?MathJax - 

Example in the gallery:
http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html

Comment: @Tonio Liebrand Yes, this works for me but only in `renderUI`. When I try to use this syntax for the column names of a `data.frame` it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right. It is tricky, because of the convention on how to name columns for data frames. Here is a possible solution:
Edit: Solution only worked for static tables.
Update:
Help can be found here: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/168
So afaik, it only will work with DT::....

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)


ui <- fluidPage(
  withMathJax(),
  selectInput("number", "Number:", 1:4),
  DT::dataTableOutput('table')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  proxy = dataTableProxy('table')

  observe({
    replaceData(proxy, df(), rownames = FALSE)
  })

  df <- reactive({
    df = data.frame(index = 1)
    df['$$\\rho_1$$'] <- input$number[1]
    df['$$\\rho_2$$'] <- 2
    df['$$\\rho_3$$'] <- 3
    df['$$\\rho_4$$'] <- 4
    df['$$\\rho_5$$'] <- 5
    # workaround to get rid of first column
    df[ , names(df)[-1]]
  })

  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(rownames = FALSE, {
    isolate(df())
  })

}


runApp(shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Comment: Somehow this works only for static tables. As soon as there is some reactivity it is not rendering the math correctly after an input change.